# Bluetooth low energy digital thermometer approvals

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, certification

We have developed a bluetooth low energy digital thermometer and need to know what certification processes we need to go through to be able to sell it in the USA.  I am happy about the EU and the UK with the CE self certification but unsure of the USA process.

The unit uses an approved BLE Module and an approved plug in PSU (for charging).  Do I need to go through independent testing of the finished product or will the already approved certification be enough?

Comment: There could also be a need (requirement?) for UL certification.  UL= Underwriters Laboratories ( UL.com).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that if your digital device is capable of plugging into mains power, you will have to at least get unintentional radiator testing done. From what I hear (no personal experience, just research), testing for unintentional radiators is relatively cheap and easy. The sparkfun link below estimates the cost at about $1500.

For intentional radiators, it seems that using a certified device with modular approval, **subject to the module's grant restrictions**, allows you to use the certification of the module.  You still have to have the unintentional radiator testing done though.

See:

http://www.rfi-global.com/images/uploads/file/FCC%20Certification%20-%20Overview%20For%20Integrated%20Wireless%20Devices.pdf

http://www.digikey.com/en-US/articles/techzone/2011/mar/the-fcc-road-part-15-from-concept-to-approval

https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/398